# What Is the proper way to reasaign Class Instance attributes that are declared in __init__ function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, instance

I am new to python and am having difficulty finding the best method to reassign variables declared in the init function (In sense of readability and logic). I am using Python 3.6.4

I have function callMyclass() which creates an instance of Myclass passing (atr1,atr2).
then it calls main_loop to assign a new values to Instance attributes declared in **init**.

**Is the best practice to only assign Instance attributes inside main_loop() or is it acceptable to reassign self.attr3 in foo2()? As well is there better alternative to accomplish I am trying to do?**

```
def callMyclass():
    instance1 = Myclass(attr1,attr2) #create instance
    instance1.main_loop()


class Myclass:

    def __init__(attr1,attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
        self.attr3 = 0

    def foo1(self, attr1, attr2):
        attr1 += attr2     #method1 
        return attr1       #return local attr1 to mainloop

    def foo2(self, attr3): #method2
        attr3 = attr3 + 3  #assaign instance attr3 here     
        self.attr3 = attr3

    def main_loop(self):       
        self.attr1 = self.foo1(attr1, attr2) #method1
        self.foo2(attr3)    #method2

        #option1: assign new value to instance attr inside main 
        #option2: call function to change instance attr
```

A slightly better example of my script structure. I have a Class with a function called main_loop() to to call function A(),B(),C()...etc.

function A() finds new values for instance attributes. 
I assign these attributes inside of function A().

An alternative method is to return these variables to main_loop and then assign new values to instance attributes from one location.

```
       Class1
            def __init__():
                self.a = 1
                self.b = 2
                self.c = 3

            def A(self)
                def nested_a(a):
                    a += 1
                    return a

                def nested_b(b):
                    b = b * 2
                    return b

                def nested_c(c):
                    c = c/ 3
                    return c

                self.a = nested_a(a)
                self.b = nested_b(b)
                self.c = nested_c(c)

            def main_loop(self):
                self.def A()

     analysis = Class1()
     analysis.main_loop()
```

Thank you so much for feedback any tips or advice is highly welcome,

Antony

Comment: I don't think there's a well-defined "best practice" for this, besides **do whatever is clearest**. See also [guides to writing pythonic code](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/) and [the zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: OK thanks for the guides they had some great insights for better style.